# Best way too add a "Custom TimeSpan format Specifier" to support 10th's of minutes

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, timespan

I have this absurd situation where i need to support a Custom TimeSpan Format with a unit of Tenths of minutes with Timespan.TryParse.

i.e. hh:mm:t

where t denotes 10ths of minute (6 second intervals)

What would be the easiest way of adding this to the Custom Timespan format parsing specifies?

Is there some override facility that would make this easy?

**Edit**

```
var mask = "hmmt";
var value = "0011";

// 0 hours
// 01 minutes
// 1 tenths of minutes


TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, mask, null, out time)
```

the mask is configurable by the user and i need the ability to add some sort of custom specifier like "t" to denote tenths of minutes
the user in essence adds this mask, as the value comes from various pabx phone systems that output duration's in many weird and wonderful ways. one of those ways is the use of 10ths of minutes

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?..can you post some code of what you have tried,not very clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, then for example .3 at the end means 3/10 of a minute, making it 18 seconds. If so, this is the way, in case you have time like "hh:mm:t" as you wrote:

```
public static class TimeSpanExtension
{
    public static TimeSpan TryParseTenth(string timeSpanString)
    {
        //change following line to accomodate date format if needed
        timeSpanString += "0";
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(timeSpanString, out ts))
        {
            // recalculate from tenth of minute into seconds
            float realSeconds = ts.Seconds * 60 / 100;

            //final operation to correct
            return ts.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, ts.Seconds - (int)realSeconds));
        }
        else
            return TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
   string time = "06:55:3";
   var timeSpan = TimeSpanExtension.TryParseTenth(time);
```

resulting in 6h55m18s as I wrote at the top

Comment: + if you really need to use TimeSpan.TryParse, then you have to take a tenth of a second out of the string, make it into seconds and return in to the string

Comment: in the end the mask needs to be configurable to deal with tenths of seconds, so i guess what your saying is ill need to pre parse the mask, change it to seconds "s", then modify it after the fact to deal with tenths of minutes

Comment: well it depends, i dont understand fully what types of masks you want to support .. I did not understood what can you have at the beginning, give me some examples of strings you can start with, and then I will try to make something out of it

Comment: although if you have proper time strings, then I suggest doing regular TryParse and then just modify timespan with the formula I included in the method. if you have different masks but the time strings are proper, use TryParseExact of TimeSpan